Pass test artifacts to upstream pipeline in GitLab CI
The upstream merge request pipeline triggers a multi-platform downstream pipeline which build and run hundreds tests through different jobs for various platforms (for instance, linux/win/mac+intel/arm+32/64).
In case it'd not use a downstream, the test results are reported and shown into the pipeline result, "Test summary" page. In case of using downstream, the test reports are left in the downstream pipeline, and not propagated to the upstream.
I'm able to download test artifacts from the downstream pipeline, and put them into the upstream through GitLab API, although it's not easy. However, it becomes a complete mess since I download results of different downstream jobs into a single upstream job to make test reports available in MR.
Is there any other way to propagate them into upstream's MR report, at least preserving the test report structure, I mean job names and test suites?
